# From behind a proxy, I can find things in the Eclipse market place, but fail installing them

Tags: eclipse, proxy

I have read about everything there is to read about Eclipse and proxies, to no avail.

I have Eclipse (Oxygen on Oracle Java 8, Photon on OpenJDK 10), both on Windows 7 in a corporate network.

I have configured the Eclipse proxy settings: Manual, with HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS all checked, but only HTTP configured with the actual proxy setting.

When using the market place, I can search for plugins just fine.
When I click 'Install', I'm getting an 'Unknown host' error.

Looking at this with Wireshark, I can see the request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p going to the proxy as it should, and the response coming just fine.

However, when I click 'Install', Eclipse sends a DNS request, for eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org in this case, instead of going straight to the proxy. This fails. Obviously, eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org is not in the proxy exclusion list.

Any ideas?

**Side-notes**

1.
I do get these messages in the Eclipse error log, which others report, too:

System property http.proxyPort is not set but should be 8080
System property http.proxyHost is not set but should be genproxy

However, adding these to eclipse.ini only results in

System property http.proxyPort has been set to 8080 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences.

etc.

2. The .log in the workspace has a number of errors like the following. Note that other parts of Eclipse apparently are also affected.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide 2 17 2018-10-30 17:06:33.066
!MESSAGE Server ‘org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server’ failed with exception: dev.eclipse.org. ; version: 2.0.7.v20170906-1327
!STACK 0
java.net.UnknownHostException: dev.eclipse.org
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.internalExecute(Request.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor.execute(Executor.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.request(IO.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.refreshConfiguration(IO.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.ServerConnection.startUp(ServerConnection.java:124)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2018-10-30 17:07:20.240
!MESSAGE Connection to https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org/p2.index failed on eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0
java.net.UnknownHostException: eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:262)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with Eclipse 2018-09 (Oxygen and Photon are outdated)? What is the exact error message? Are there more details in the log?

Comment: Log above. Yes, 2018-09 behaves in exactly the same way.

Comment: Which DNS addresses are configured in Windows 7? Is at least one of these addresses a public DNS and not in the proxy exclusion list?

Comment: The DNS addresses are for the internal corporate network only, which is why the resolution of eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org fails. The question is: Why does Eclipse even attempt to resolve that hostname? It shouldn't, because I told it to use a proxy.

Comment: How else should the domain name be resolved to an IP address? Does in Windows 7 configure e. g. `1.1.1.1` as secondary DNS solve your issue?

Comment: It doesn't have to. The request for the marketplace catalog is a simple "HTTP/1.0 GET  http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p" which is sent to the proxy. The proxy's name is obviously resolved, but marketplace.eclipse.org is not - the proxy will take care of that.

Comment: [I see](https://serverfault.com/a/352180), thanks for the explanation. Please [report it to Eclipse Marketplace Client (MPC)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=MPC).

Comment: Thanks, howlger. I've created [bug 540735](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540735).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **also configure a proxy for HTTPS** to be able to download [SonarLint](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint) via the Eclipse Marketplace Client.

The [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) is just a catalog of items that refer to update sites from which the artifacts to be installed are downloaded. These update sites can be HTTP or **HTTPS**. The **SonarLint update site** URL starts with `https://`:

[image]